# Building Tensorflow

Tags: android, tensorflow

I want to build tensorflow for my android smartphone. So I´ve installed [bazel](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/windows.html) and get the sources for tensorflow.

`git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`

I modify the `WORKSPACE` file with my paths for the NDK and the SDK

```
android_sdk_repository(
    name = "androidsdk",
    api_level = 27,
    build_tools_version = "27.0.3",
    # Replace with path to Android SDK on your system
    path = ".../AppData/Local/Android/Sdk",
)

android_ndk_repository(
    name = "androidndk",
    path = .../AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle",
    api_level = 27
)
```

And now I run bazel

`bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so \
   --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool \
   --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain \
   --cpu=armeabi-v7a`

And got this error

`fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
Target //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 72,096s, Critical Path: 14,55s
INFO: 213 processes, local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully`

How can I compile tensorflow for android with windows (or maybe ubuntu)?

Comment: your ndk-bundle path doesn't seem to be correct..also I had to use absolute paths instead of relative paths